How can I modelling Company Node in Neo4J for Stock Database?
I am wondering if anybody can share knowledge model stock database in Neo4J.
At first I have Company Node.
Use Case 1 is:
At 2002 a company name is different for Example "Company A". And Then it can change there Name, MA with company B and change the name to Company C.
Use Case 2 is: At 2002 company A have 100 share (for example) and then the amount of share can be increased.
Use case 3 is: At 2002 company A can own 60 percent of a company Z.
So confuse when modelling and I need help.
How can I modelling Company Node to solve such case?
THanks.

Something like this:  UC#1: (:Company {name: companyC})-[:PREVIOUS_NAME]->(:Company {name: companyB}) -[:PREVIOUS_NAME]->(:Company {name: companyA}) UC#2: This is a simple property in :Company node like  company.amountShare: 100   UC#3: (:Company {name: companyA}) -[:OWNS {percentage: 60}]-> (:Company {name:companyZ})

Thanks you for your suggestion.
In UC2.  I am wondering of keeping number of share as a properties of Company Node. Because this number can be change many times and each time it change the number of share related Company Node or Person Node (the person who own the share) can change number and percentage. And I also want to know it.

Neoj can store data only in two ways: 1) node property in Company  2) another node :Shares  with number: and percentage: as properties.  As you can see in other option, you still need to match :Company -> :Shares then update property under :Shares.  Btw, updating the data as often should not be an issue as long as you code it properly. Let me know your thoughts.

I am thinking as you suggested. A Company Node name:Company A, and a Share Node Code as AAA and numberOfShare: 1000. Then as the time being Company a can Increase number of shares from 1000 to 2000. I have another Share Node with the same code and the properties is different 2000 (not 1000) it is not good.

Perhaps the following option will suit you.
Node: Company
Properties:

shareCode
sharesOutstanding (total shares issued)

Node: CompanyName
Properties:

name

Relationship: use (between the Company and the CompanyName)
Properties:

since

Relationship: own (between the Company and the Company. Note that company A can own some shares of itself, then the parent and child nodes for this relationship will match)
Properties:

numberOfShares (not a percentage, a percentage is equal (numberOfShares * 100)/sharesOutstanding)

